# Setting faillure conditions in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, conditional-statements

How can I set in Jmeter the conditions to establish that a sample has been a success or a failure according to its response time?

For example making Jmeter to consider that a sample with a response time above 10000 milliseconds is a fail and a sample with a response time under 10000 milliseconds is a success.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) as a child to the sampler in which you want to assert the response times.

In `Duration in milliseconds` field, add value `10000`.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work in Beanshell Assertion. In addition, it will abort the current iteration and the virtual user will proceed to the next iteration from the beginning

```
try {
    Long restime = SampleResult.getTime();

    if (restime > 10000) {      
        Failure = true;
        ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true);       
    }
    else    { 
        Failure = false;
        //AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
    }   
}
catch ( Exception ex) {
        Failure = true;
        ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true);       
}
```