# Two Conditions in Jmeter While Loop

Tags: jmeter

This is not an [overlap question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092776/setting-faillure-conditions-in-jmeter), My Question:

I have two condition in my Jmeter while loop.

Condition 1: Checks for response text
Condition 2: Wants to check whether there is any error on page or not and in case yes, move to next sample and mark it as failure

```
${__javaScript( "${EME}" != "First Pass Yield" && "${EME_ERROR}" = "Odbc driver returned an error")}
```

Above condition variable `${EME}` check for the response text and it works fine but at the same page i want to check if in case there's an error i should be able to capture that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For equal between string use `==` and not `=`. I checked the following and it worked

```
${__javaScript("${EME}" != "First Pass Yield" && "${EME_ERROR}" == "Odbc driver returned an error")}
```

If you hover over the condition Jmeter suggest use jexl3 for performance. so you can equally execute jexl statement:

```
${jexl3("${EME}" != "First Pass Yield" && "${EME_ERROR}" == "Odbc driver returned an error")}
```